# How to build a text from data?

Tags: app-inventor

I'm developing an app using MIT App Inventor 2, and there's a feature where you filled text box with data required and send it to someone through WhatsApp. For example, there are three fields : name, dob, and pob. I filled the name as "abcd", I filled the dob as "January 1 2000" and I filled the pob as "London". I want to send the data to someone with this templates through whatsapp.

```
My Biodata
Name : abcd
Date of Birth : January 1, 2000
Place of Birth : London
```

How to make the templates on App Inventor? I already found out how to send the templates but not how to make the templates.

Answer (score 0):

use for example a global variable to store your text and use **\n** for a new line

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)